# A rhetorical question which the author then answers

Tags: syntactic-analysis, question-tags

What is the name of the question which is bold in the following?

> I want to shift the discipline from physics to biology. **Why?** Because, …

You ask it not because you don't know something, but because you think that people will ask it right after you state something. Its appearance is not required; you can get rid of it without changing the meaning.

Note that this kind of question is not necessarily short:

> I want to shift the discipline from physics to biology. **Why would I want this?** Because, …

Comment: "Pre-emptive" may work - as in, you're pre-empting the audiences question, before answering it.

Comment: @BlessedGeek Over here it's generally pronounced "sep-er-ate" - it's certainly a word that catches me out

Comment: "Over here"? When I was in Maine, or when I was in TX, or when I was in CO, or when I was in CT, or MA and now in OR and WA, people pronounce it and spell it the same way. Which country are you from, when you say "over here"? It is pronounced seprat as an adjective and sepe'rate as a verb. I've never heard anyone pronounce it as sep er ate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called **[hypophora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypophora)**.  It's a common type of rhetorical question.

Technically, that is what the *question* is called.  The answer is apparently called [anthyphophora](http://mannerofspeaking.org/2012/01/25/rhetorical-devices-hypophora/).  You can check out some examples of it [here](http://literarydevices.net/hypophora/); one of the examples is very similar to what you've quoted.  That link also includes a definition.

Comment: Do we call it "hypophora question" or just "hypophora" is enough?

Comment: Just hypophora.

Comment: what are all the types of rhetorical questions?